# A question regarding series.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

So i have a question regarding series and how test works. Given we have the series

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty {\dfrac{n}{e^n}}$

Doing the Divergence test on this series, i would interpet that as

$\lim_{n \to \infty}$${\dfrac{n}{e^n}}$=${\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}}$

And i really dont know what to make of this. For now i have just interpeted it as it meaning the divergence test is inconclusive and some other test is needed. Am i going wrong somewhere in that understanding?

Comment: I think if you write out (in your question) what the "Divergence Test" is, and precisely how you have used it. This should help you. Because I think you have used it incorrectly.

Comment: Presumably you have seem some methods for evaluating limits of the "undetermined form" $\frac 00$ or $\frac {\infty}{\infty}$.

Comment: You can use L'Hopitals rule, but that will give you a limit of zero, so still inconclusive. Try a comparison test or use the ratio test if you have learned it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I guess I'm asking what does the divergence test and similar ones say about series where you end up with indeterminate forms when you let the limit tend towards infinity

Comment: @Chawken Nothing. For instance if you have $\sum n/(n+1)^2$, or $\sum n/(n+1)^3$... both have indeterminant form. First diverges, second converges.

Comment: "you end up with indeterminate forms" only means you have failed to compute the limit by the simplest possible method.  As @lulu says, to apply the test you must actually compute the limit (which is a task about computing limits only).

Comment: Just as a fun fact, this sum evaluates to $\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$. In fact, there exists a general closed form for sums of this form.

Answer (score 1):

Given series is $\,\color{blue}{\displaystyle{{S}_{\infty}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}{x}_{n}}}\,$  , where $\,\color{green}{{x}_{n}=\dfrac{n}{{e}^{n}}}$

To test whether it is convergent or divergent, let us perform D'Alembert's Ratio test.

> Let $\,\color{magenta}{\sum{x}_{n}}\,$ be a series of positive real numbers and $\,\color{magenta}{\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{{x}_{n+1}}{{x}_{n}}=l}\,$
>
> Then $\,(i)\color{magenta}{\sum{x}_{n}}\,$ is convergent if $\,\color{magenta}{l<1}\,,\,\,\,\,(ii)\color{magenta}{\sum{x}_{n}}\,$ is divergent if $\,\color{magenta}{l>1}$

So, let us perform the ratio test.

$\,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{{x}_{n+1}}{{x}_{n}}\,$

$\,\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{n+1}{{e}^{n+1}}}{\dfrac{n}{{e}{n}}}\,$

$\,\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{(n+1){e}^{n}}{n\,{e}^{n+1}}\,$

$\,\displaystyle=\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+1}{n\,e}\,$

$\,\displaystyle=\dfrac{1}{e}\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n+1}{n}\,$

$\,\displaystyle=\dfrac{1}{e}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\,$

$\,\displaystyle=\dfrac{1}{e}\,$

So, the limit $\,\displaystyle\color{magenta}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{{x}_{n+1}}{{x}_{n}}}\,<1\,$

**Hence, according to the ratio test, the given series is convergent**

Answer (score 0):

From the power series
for $e^x$,
$e^n > n^k/k!$
for all $k$.
Setting $k=3$,
$e^n>n^3/6$
so $n/e^n < 6/n^2$
and the sum of this converges.